# Hide a Tab on tabBarController from a view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to hide / deactivate a Tab on a `UITabBarController` ??

And how?

Comment: Is it possible to REMOVE words in ALL CAPS???

Comment: Yes it is possible (to remove words in call caps) :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to deactivate it, use following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController; 
{
    if (viewControllerYouWantToDeactivate == viewController)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }   
}
```

Don't forget to set delegate of your `UITabBarController`.

You can find delegate [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)